# How to ensure ssh via cgroups on centos?

Tags: linux, ssh, cgroup

When some cpu-intensive processes are running on the server, chances are that we could not log in to this machine with error 'operation timeout' via `ssh` command.

According to this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56538/controlling-priority-of-applications-using-cgroups) answered by peterph, there should be a way to guarantee sshd service on any circumstances. But I just don't know how to **create a group for sshd, give it some non-negligible CPU time share, and give this "remote access" processes much higher CPU share then the rest**.

Could anyone tell me how can I configure it in "/etc/cgconfig.conf" and "/etc/cgrules.conf"? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to fix the root cause of this resource contention rather than cgroup trickery. Even on my systems with intensive workloads, SSH access has never been an issue.

- What type of server is this?
- What are the specifications of the hardware/OS/distribution?
- And what the heck is happening on the system to prevent sshd from responding consistently?

Also, is there any chance that you're facing *entropy* depletion?

Comment: Cannot upvote this answer enough. Restricting resources is OK but root-cause is the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: My environment is centos6.4, 60GB RAM, 24 CPU. If the root cause is iowait is very high with 2000 processes executing `hadoop get` simultaneously, will it be helpful if I set the maximum number of processes a user can fork? Thanks.